# Wireless/audio not working on Dell Vostro 15 5590 with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless, sound, dell

I am posting this as I've gone through several posts here and couldn't understand exactly the issues I'm having and the solution.
I recently bought a Dell Vostro 15 5590 (see [here](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/vostro-15-5590-laptop_owners-manual2_en-us.pdf) for all specs). Relevant hardware information:

- 10th Generation Intel Core i7-10510U
- Wireless adapter Intel 9462 NGW
- Audio controller Realtek ALC3204

It came with Windows 10, but then I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS alongside it. When I first booted into Ubuntu, I noticed the wireless wasn't working. The card wasn't even showing up in the UI, but with `lspci` I could see it. After a thorough search I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180765/intel-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu) which worked. I basically installed the `linux-oem-osp1` package and after a reboot I was able to connect to a Wi-Fi network.

However, I then noticed that the audio wasn't working, neither input nor output. In the UI it was only showing the dummy output but again through `lspci` I could find my sound card. Found some questions here but nothing worked. Does anyone have any clue about this?

**UPDATE:** About the sound issues, I tried all the alternatives provided in [this link](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/). For the step where I should run the alsamixer utility, it failed with the message `cannot open mixer: No such file or directory`. I believe that is because it cannot find any sound card?

**UPDATE WITH PARTIAL SOLUTION:** By following the steps suggested by Pedro below, I was able to have sound output and wi-fi working. It basically consists on **going back to the kernel 5.0.0-37-generic**, which makes the sound work, and then installing the package `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` with the commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
$ reboot
```

The internal microphone still doesn't work, although the microphone of a headset works fine. I will go after this issue now and will update this with more info if I get it to work.

Comment: Lucas, thank you for bravely pushing on and solving the WiFi issue. Now, to help with the sound card problem, we need to know specifically what commands you ran, and what the exact result of each was, to avoid asking you to reinvent the wheel. Please click on [edit] and add that essential information to your original question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have updated my question with the info.

Comment: Have added a bounty of 50 pts from my personal bank to draw attention to this, as I am up to my eyeballs in other work. May the force be with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manage to solve it. I have the exact same configs as yours and I've been through the same situation. I noticed

- kernel 5.0.0-37-generic - wifi adapter **not** working, sound working
- kernel linux-oem-osp1 - wifi adapter working, sound **not** working

First, I plugged in the good old ethernet cable and went back to kernel 5.0.0-37-generic. You can boot another kernel in the grub menu and make it the default. So, sound is on.

Secondly I tried lots of ways to make the wifi adapter work, this was the only one that really did it.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
$ reboot
```

not sure if this is the optimal way, but now wifi and sound are working.

I'll start my research about input audio now, I'll come back and edit if I somehow get it working.

Comment: Perfect! It did not come to my mind to go back to the previous kernel version to check if the sound would work and then fix the wi-fi. Now the only remaining issue is the microphone. Headphone's mic works fine, but the internal mic is not even recognized. I also found out now that the right button of the touchpad works as the left button, so the only way to right-click is by double tapping. I'm checking a few things and will update my question with info.

Comment: Follow-up about the touchpad, simply following the steps in this link worked for me: https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu

Comment: That indeed works, but I personally prefer using double touch to right click anyways, didn't even realized it was off. 
What about the microphone input? Did you find something?

Comment: Not yet. I tried several things but no success. I've been busy these last few days so couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : 
- [Intel Wifi Card not working on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180765/intel-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu)

Maybe you can Try to reinstall PulseAudio and Alsa by opening a terminal and doing the following:

- Purge Alsa and PulseAudio using the command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
  ```
- Install Alsa and PulseAudio again:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
  ```
- Reload Alsa:

  ```
  sudo alsa force-reload
  ```
- Done. Check again if the sound is working.

  If not, try:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```

Maybe you want to also check this out:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

Comment: Already did something similar and didn't work. Did what you said just for the sake but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://leimao.github.io/blog/Ubuntu-No-Sound-Fix/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Dell Vostro 5590 for a few days now, and had a similar problem. I did quite a lot of different things to make this laptop usable with Ubuntu so I cannot exactly say what helped me, but at some point I have noticed that the sound was working with kernel **5.0.0-37** (but no WiFI), but it was gone when switching to 5.0.0-1030-oem-osp1 (WIFI was working). After comparing the info returned by *lspci -vv* I have noticed the difference in **Kernel driver in use** of my **Multimedia audio controller**. It was set to **sof-audio-pci** for oem-osp1 kernel build (sound not working) and **snd_hda_intel** for 5.0.0-37.
I started to play with Alsa settings and added **options snd-hda-intel dsp_driver=0** at the end of */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf* file.

In a meanwhile I have also upgraded the system to 19.10 and tried with newer kernels, but always either WIFI, or sound was not working. I don't know exactly what I did, but suddenly both WIFI and sound started to work on Ubuntu 19.10 with kernel 5.3.0-24. **lspci -vv** shows it is using **snd_hda_intel** driver now.

Next issue I need to solve is not working build-in microphone.

I know it is not a solution to your problem, but I hope it may give you some clue that will help you find it.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'm going through right now. I saw that sof-audio-pci is in use, but did not know if sound was working before I started figuring out the wi-fi issues (probably was). The fix seems to be just trying to force the system to use the right driver. snd_hda_intel shows up in kernel modules on lspci, but the one in use is still the sof-audio-pci.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Dell Vostro 5590.

For audio (Realtek ALC3204) you have to stay on the Kernel 5.3.0-43-generic x86_64 for the moment and modify the default startup in Grub.

For Wireless (Intel Wireless-AC 9462) follow this procedure (Attention if you change Kernel you will lose your wireless configuration again)
In the terminal as follows:

```
sudo apt install git build-essential

git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git

cd backport-iwlwifi

make defconfig-iwlwifi-public

sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config

make -j4

sudo make install

cd /lib/firmware

sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode

sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-38.ucode
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by jylyknight is working. Below you can see how to install kernel.  It also work with Dell Vostro 7590
For 64-bit OS:

```
cd /tmp/
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-headers-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-image-unsigned-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3/linux-modules-5.3.0-050300-generic_5.3.0-050300.201909152230_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

How to set old kernel in grub? Below instruction

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

set in grub

```
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15
```

this will allow you to choose kernel during start. Choose 5.3