# Laptop cannot init iwlwifi

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, iwlwifi

Ubuntu 18.04 can't detect my laptop's Wifi adapter, Intel AC 9560. This seemed to happen randomly the same day that I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. This seems to be a result of iwlwifi not initializing correctly. As suggested by some other posts here, I installed the backported iwlwifi to upgrade the firmware from version 43 to 46. Iwlwifi still cannot initialize after the upgrade. What else can I try?

dmesg | grep iwlwifi

```
[    7.141818] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    7.141818] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8292:84649f87
[    7.166504] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[    7.174431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    7.174433] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    7.174434] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    7.174434] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    7.174435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    7.174435] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    7.174436] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    7.174437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    7.174437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    7.174438] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    7.174439] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    7.174439] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    7.174440] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    7.174441] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.174442] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    7.174715] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    7.175719] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    7.246305] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    8.257790] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x0
[    8.506015] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    8.506031] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    8.506039] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2D115451 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    8.506047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    8.506055] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAEC27F45 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    8.506064] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    8.506072] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEC256552 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    8.506081] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05550E5D | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    8.506089] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0EE961BB | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    8.506097] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD6131860 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    8.506105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.506146] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    8.506220] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    8.506294] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    8.506303] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -110
[    8.519833] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seemed to do the trick! Thanks for the help.

dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    5.375574] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.375575] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    5.375864] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.435243] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    5.442189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    5.442333] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    5.482708] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[    5.566650] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.587163] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    7.356455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.470075] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.534778] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

**EDIT:**

As noted in this comment, https://askubuntu.com/a/1203223/1032323, the audio fails after employing the solution described here, https://askubuntu.com/a/1201620/1032323. In my experience, my laptop also fails to shutdown or reboot without hanging. So, I booted the original kernel and followed the instructions here [Wireless/audio not working on Dell Vostro 15 5590 with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198762/wireless-audio-not-working-on-dell-vostro-15-5590-with-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts). This solution solves the audio and shutdown problems but the `iwlwifi` driver can fail after suspending the laptop. I can reload the driver to solve this but I'm looking for a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please see this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1835879 It suggests that your device is not supported but is supported in the package linux-oem-osp1.

Your device also requires firmware that is not present in the linux-firmware package in 18.04. Let's fix both. With a temporary internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.183.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

And next:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1
```

Several dependencies will also be installed.

Reboot and show us a new:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: I think the URL of the first snippet is missing the wget command. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The new firmware is causing errors with my audio output

and the iwlwifi issue recurs after a few boots and reboots

Could you please check again?

Comment: I encountered the same issue. I ended up booting from my original kernel and following the instructions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198762/wireless-audio-not-working-on-dell-vostro-15-5590-with-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts. One thing that I've found with this solution is that `iwlwifi` fails after sleep. Reloading the driver using modprobe seems to solve this problem but I'm looking for a more permanent solution.