# Intel wireless 9650 unclaimed network

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I am very new to Ubuntu and am using 19.10. The wireless internet kept telling me my password was incorrect and the prompt to type it in was on an endless loop. I accidentally `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` and now my wifi has completely disappeared. I've been trying everything include `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` but have had no luck. 
When I type `dmesg | grep iwl` nothing happens. The only relevant information I have is
 `sudo lshw -c network` produces

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 30
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:b431c000-b431ffff
 *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:6
   logical name: enx00e04c6804d2
   serial: 00:e0:4c:68:04:d2
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.10 duplex=full ip=192.168.0.46 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

**EDIT**

`sudo modprobe iwlwifi` This does nothing now

`dmesg | grep iwl`

```
[    2.435843] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    2.435844] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7906:7773a757
[    2.502602] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.504534] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-   cfg.ini failed with error -2
[    2.507436] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.507437] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.507924] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version     46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.701211] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    2.708455] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination     EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.708920] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for  firmware monitor.
[    2.753744] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: d0:ab:d5:17:9e:f4
[    2.825134] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-    mvm-rs'
[    2.827381] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[    4.637929] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.756187] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.824996] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   56.786408] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[   56.786852] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[   59.858918] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[   59.860223] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
 00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0034]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

`sudo dkms status`

```
backport-iwlwifi, 7906, 5.0.0-1030-oem-osp1, x86_64: installed
backport-iwlwifi, 7906, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 430.50, 5.0.0-1030-oem-osp1, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 430.50, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did the `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` you removed the wifi driver module from the kernel. Why did you do that? Don't ever type commands in the `terminal` if you're not 100% what they do.

To reload it, type `sudo modprobe iwlwifi`. Or, reboot the computer.

Regarding the wifi password, assure that your CAPS LOCK key is off, and assure that you're typing the correct password, including any upper/lower case letters. The password is case-sensitive. Assure that both sides of the wifi connection are using WPA2. Reset the wifi password if necessary.

**Update #1:**

- we found that Secure Boot had been enabled.

**Update #2:**

- You updated/upgraded the kernel from `5.0.0-1030-oem-osp1` to `5.3.0-26-generic`.
- `dkms status` shows us backport-iwlwifi.

`sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/7906 --all`

`reboot`

**Update #3:**

And from [Laptop cannot init iwlwifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201546/laptop-cannot-init-iwlwifi/1201620#1201620) we get:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.183.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Thanks @chili555

Comment: I read somewhere to do that but I've already tried to do `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and it gives me this error `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Operation not permitted`. Additionally, my caps lock key is always off I know for sure I typed my password in perfectly.

Comment: @abish5 did you start the command with `sudo`? Otherwise, reboot the computer and that should fix it also. Regarding the password, are both sides set to use WPA2?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` and also:`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: @chili555 Okay I've changed it accordingly.

Comment: @abish5  Did you reboot yet?

Comment: Yes, I've rebooted 3 different times and nothing has changed

Comment: @abish5 had you done anything else other than the `modprobe -r` command?

Comment: Nope, I did modprobe -r  iwlwifi and then tried to do modprobe iwlwifi right after and it gave me that error. I've rebooted but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: @abish5 you didn't answer my earlier query... did you use `sudo`?

Comment: Sorry, yes I started with sudo.

Comment: Lets see what @chili555 has to say.

Comment: @abish5 Did you change the Secure Boot setting in your BIOS?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Please disable secure boot and then let's also see: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: Does the wireless work now without secure boot?

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, I will be off for the evening. I think he does NOT need backport-iwlwif but DOES need linux-oem-osp1. Turn off secure boot and Chili's yer uncle! See you all later.

Comment: Thank you secure boot fixed it but connected to the wifi still gives me an endless loop.

Comment: @abish5 So... how did Secure Boot get enabled? Did you check that the wireless is using WPA2 at both ends? Did you reset the wifi password?

Comment: I disabled it when rebooting and that fixed. I'm not sure how to check if WPA2 is working at both ends.

Comment: @abish5 when/why did you install backport-iwlwifi?

Comment: @heynnema I'm not too sure what you mean I never installed it?

Comment: Do Update #2 in my answer.

Comment: `Error!  Unknown option: -iwlwifi/7906` Got this error any ideas?

Comment: @abish5 `backport-iwlwifi` is all one text with no spaces. Copy/paste the command.

Comment: Still not connecting after reboot it just tells me it's wrong.

Comment: @abish5 You rebooted, yes? Show me the current status of `dkms status`.

Comment: `nvidia, 430.50, 5.0.0-1030-oem-osp1, x86_64: installed`
`nvidia, 430.50, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: @abish5 I'll ask it again... you rebooted, yes?

Comment: Yes I rebooted after update #2

Comment: @abish5 It's bedtime here. I leave you with this... log into the router and reset the wifi password, and see if that fixes the problem. I'll leave a message for chili555 for later.

Comment: @chili555 please see Update #1 and Update #2 in my answer for current status. OP updated his kernel, and I suspect that things went wrong after that. Please keep me posted.

Comment: Thanks, I woke up today and it just suddenly started to work.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.

Comment: @chili555 I just woke up myself. Just curious... what is `linux-oem-osp1`, and how/why did you suspect that it might need reinstall? Apparently OP **did** have that, but it was superseded by a kernel update/upgrade. It's unclear the entire sequence of events here, as obviously more was done than just a `modprobe -r`.

Comment: @heynnema It's very unclear, indeed. `linux-oem-osp1` is a package that makes the latest Intel devices work correctly. Its exact nature is unclear to me. It was suggested  to me (and later proven to be effective) at this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem-osp1/+bug/1835879 Also see the accepted answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201546/laptop-cannot-init-iwlwifi/1201620#1201620

Comment: @chili555 See the comment to your answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201546/laptop-cannot-init-iwlwifi/1201620#1201620. It's missing wget? And tell me if I'm wrong, but it looks like just the firmware update is required.

Comment: @heynnema Yup, thanks; editted. The required firmware is not likely in 18.04. I know it's in 19.10 et seq so I err on the side of caution if the OP is running anything older than 19.10 and install firmware.