# Installation problem Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, error-handling

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron machine.

- I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 from the website and burnt the iso file on a DVD.
- Then changed the Boot menu for the external DVD writer. It was no problem until here
- Done the installation part as well.

But, when I restarted the machine it comes to a certain point and writes out error messages. And after this error message it refuses to go ahead:

```
iwlwifi:0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110.
```

Which part of the process did not go well?

Comment: That is your wireless driver; See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201546/laptop-cannot-init-iwlwifi and https://askubuntu.com/a/1201620/15811  BUT that requires you to be able to install software. Might need to connect your system through wired internet or bluetooth.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot enter the system, it hangs there permanently at this point.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is four years old. Consider trying a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: iwlwifi is in the Linux kernel, but you may need a newer version of it than you have. I also suggest using Ubuntu 18.04 instead.