# Firmware problem: iwlwifi not working

Tags: networking, 20.04, iwlwifi, firmware

since yesterday I'm facing the problem that I can't use W-LAN or Bluetooth with my Laptop device. I was running several commands from other threads (see below), but none was helping. At the end I booted the system with a different Kernel I had installed and finally the W-LAN worked again.

Today, the yesterday's issue appeared again but this time I'm unable to figure out how to get along. Any help is appreciated.

[Here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg3401720.html), the error output looks similar to the one I've got, but execution of the commands `rmmod` and `modprobe` did not help.
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201546/laptop-cannot-init-iwlwifi) did not help either.

System OS: **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS** with Kernel **5.4.0-89-generic x86_64**

My device's network controller: **Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462**

`lspci -kvnn | sed -n '/Network/,/^$/ p'` gives some more details:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:02f0]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:02a4]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at c431c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`dmesg | grep iwlwifi` outputs:

```
[    5.998179] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.012643] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 58.3.35.22
[    6.012888] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 50.3e391d3e.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.068201] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x354
[    7.093785] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    7.093880] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    7.093881] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: -330306978
[    7.093882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 50.3e391d3e.0
[    7.093883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB7E103D4 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    7.093883] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x988EB45E | trm_hw_status0

... some more lines of error output

[    7.094159] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    7.094253] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    7.094451] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
[    7.094452] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    7.094453] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    7.105807] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

## Update

Following [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6) advice to install HWE it still does not work. However the error message is more precise this time:

> Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-64.ucode failed with error -2

`uname -r` outputs **5.14.14-051414-generic**.

`dmesg | grep iwlwifi` outputs:

```
[    5.604933] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.608449] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-64.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.610141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    5.610156] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    5.610428] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.692788] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9462, REV=0x354
[    6.722141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x0, CPU2 Status: 0x3100000
[    6.722170] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC PC: 0xc00c0538
[    6.722217] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC PC: 0x0
[    6.722221] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    6.722700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.722702] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x00000042, valid: -71178302
[    6.722705] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 63.c04f3485.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-63.ucode
[    6.722707] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x89C6A936 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    6.722710] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8E507E67 | trm_hw_status0

... some more code

[    6.723211] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    6.723216] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000201 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    6.723251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.723295] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.723378] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    6.723446] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    6.723467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    6.723470] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    7.921900]  drm_kms_helper snd_timer cec iwlwifi efi_pstore intel_wmi_thunderbolt snd processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy processor_thermal_device rc_core processor_thermal_rfim processor_thermal_mbox i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_rapl ucsi_acpi(+) mxm_wmi 8250_dw ee1004 fb_sys_fops wmi_bmof intel_rapl_common typec_ucsi mei_me syscopyarea sysfillrect soundcore hid_multitouch cfg80211 sysimgblt mei intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf typec int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone mac_hid int3400_thermal acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel acpi_tad sch_fq_codel overlay iptable_filter ip6table_filter ip6_tables br_netfilter bridge stp llc arp_tables msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb uas usb_storage hid_generic crc32_pclmul i2c_hid_acpi nvme xhci_pci i2c_i801 xhci_pci_renesas intel_lpss_pci nvme_core i2c_smbus sdhci_pci ahci cqhci intel_lpss i2c_hid sdhci libahci idma64 hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
[    8.386160] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

## Update 2

@heynnema

`dkms status` outputs:

```
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.11.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.14.14-051414-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.3.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
```

`sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi` outputs the same output as before.

## Update 3

Following @unbi-rabka answer did not solve the problem.**I still do not have wireless connection**.

`sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi` outputs:

```
[    3.373741] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.381121] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 02f0/0000, rev=0x354, rfid=0x0
[    3.381223] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

Also I tried to install a brand-new installation of Ubuntu-18.04 alongside my current installation. But it did not help either.

Comment: Try to switch to HWE kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, can you provide me some information on what its purpose is and how to switch?

Comment: The purpose is to switch to the 5.14 kernel. Run `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04` and reboot. It will leave the existing kernel intact, you can switch back.

Comment: But it it is a dual boot with Windows, it's another issue.

Comment: My only OS is Linux - does this mean, your advice won't help me? What also confuses me is that until yesterday everything worked fine for almost two years without any change being made (up to what I've noticed)...

Comment: If it is NOT a dual boot, it's worth trying. Maybe firmware got an update and it's not good for the old kernel.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /lib/firmware/iwlwifi*.p*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema

 `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 41804 Okt 25 18:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm`

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27480 Okt 25 18:06 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm`

Comment: Rename those two files to add `.HOLD` to the end of their names. Reboot. Retest. Report back.

Comment: Also show me `dkms status`... and put that output into your question, not the comments please.

Comment: Question is edited @heynnema. This comment is to make sure you noticed I have answered already...

Comment: Did you rename the files and test yet? Which kernel are you running on right now? 5.14.14-051414-generic?

Comment: @heynnema The files names are `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.HOLD` and `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.HOLD` at the moment. I am running `5.14.14-051414-generic`.

Comment: Good. Now reboot and test wireless.

Comment: @heynnema I rebooted. It is still not working. The error message when running `sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi` is the one shown in the question.

Comment: Download https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz, uncompress it, put the file into /lib/firmware, reboot, retest.

Comment: Oh, here's a much never version of the firmware file... https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode

Comment: @heynnema The error remains the same. Just to be sure: there are a lot of `iwlwifi*.ucode` files in `/lib/firmware`. However the system apparently tries to load the ones starting with `iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-[number].ucode` as (as I understood it) they correspond to my device's wireless module, starting with the highest version number, which seems to be 64 and - when not finding it - looking for the next one which is 63. (see error message in the question)

Comment: You have an Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462, according to your info. Did you try the newer .ucode link that I gave?

Comment: See https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html to find the filename, and then go to https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/ to get the newest version.

Comment: @heynnema Yes. The file is inside the folder. However the system seems to always open the file `iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-[number].ucode` which does not correspond to Wireless-AC 9462. Is the firmware file name which is loaded (e.g. using `modprobe`) maybe saved in some config file? Do you know how to explicitely tell the system to use this specific firmware https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode?

Comment: Have you tried backport-iwlwifi-dkms?

Comment: @heynnema Actually I tried what is propsed in this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046589/backport-for-iwlwifi but the error message remains the same.

Comment: I'm at a loss then. Sorry.

Comment: Wait, you say this isn't a dualboot, are you in a VM?  Is this adapter directly passed to the VM or no?  The VM **should not** have any access to the host system's hardware unless USB or PCI passthrough is done (and that'll break things if your host system is using the hardware)

Comment: @ThomasWard It is not a dualboot. I am **not** using **VM**.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the problem recently (August 2022) after years of no problems with an Intel 3160 wlp2s0. One of the incremental upgrades to 20.04 I suspect. I solved it by upgrading to 22.04

Answer (score 1):

i use kubuntu 20.04 and Wifi 6E AX210

i have same issue after update os, so i try this on my pc and its works

```
mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm.bak
```

after rename, you must restart your pc

Comment: I tried it. It did not help. See Update 3 for the output...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else arriving here looking for a solution, I've had a similar issue with a laptop on **20.04**, with an **Intel 9461** adapter.

It appears to me to be a kernel/driver/firmware mismatch. I was able to resolve by upgrading the `linux-firmware` package. To do this, I looked at [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-firmware) to see the available versions of this package for **20.04** and *newer* releases.

I downloaded the newest, but that did not change the problem, so next I tried the next-newer than what is available on **20.04**, which is from **21.04 (hirsuite)** and is version **1.197**.
This **fully** resolved the problem, and should not be broken by an update, assuming any `linux-firmware` updates to **20.04** maintain their version scheme. Any updates to this package in the **focal** repository would be versioned `1.187.x > 1.187.29`, which would be greater than the current version, but *always* lower than `1.197`...

[Here is a link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/all/linux-firmware/download) to the mirrors page for a direct download to version `1.197` of the `linux-firmware` package.

**EDIT:** Scratch that! Looks like `wpa-supplicant.service` was restarted *during* the apt installation of `1.197`, and it just happened to do so when a working firmware file was the only one present in `/lib/firmware/`. Subsequently, *downgrading* to version `1.187` is giving a working combination.

I've pinned that package to the `1.187` version and now it is actually working, even after a reboot.

This is what I did on **20.04**:

```
user@computer:~$ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/linux-firmware-iwlwifi-on-5-13-0-fix 
Package: linux-firmware
Pin: release a=focal-updates
Pin-Priority: -10

Package: linux-firmware
Pin: release a=focal
Pin-Priority: 1001
```