# iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev

Tags: iwlwifi, firmware, pci

As I mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371546/firmware-problem-iwlwifi-not-working) my wireless connection is not working.
After making some changes to the firmware according to the support of some community members I ended up with the following output:

`sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi` outputs:

```
[    3.373741] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.381121] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 02f0/0000, rev=0x354, rfid=0x0
[    3.381223] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

I noticed that the last numbers of the **Subsystem** entry changed according to the last time I ran
`lspci -kvnn | sed -n '/Network/,/^$/ p'`. It now returns

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:02f0]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462 [8086:0000]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at c431c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Does anybody have a clue how I could proceed to get wireless connection again? I would also be willing to format my the whole system if necessary. However as I tried installing an 18.04 Ubuntu version alongside my 20.04 one already without any improvement I'm not sure if that helps...

## EDIT (replying to @nobody comment)

`dkms status`

```
backport-iwlwifi, 8324: added
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.11.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.14.14-051414-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
```

`uname -r` : `5.14.14-051414-generic`

`rfkill list`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`grep -i error /var/log/kern.log` -> [External file link](https://github.com/AngeloGross/iwlwifi-error/blob/main/var-log-kern-log.txt)
Here there are definitely some alarming messages like

```
Oct 24 19:57:22 angelo-P15648 kernel: [14072.342831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
Oct 24 19:57:22 angelo-P15648 kernel: [14072.342920] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE0000021 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
Oct 24 19:57:22 angelo-P15648 kernel: [14072.343325] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware error during reconfiguration - reprobe!
Oct 24 19:57:22 angelo-P15648 kernel: [14072.343674] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW error in SYNC CMD MAC_CONTEXT_CMD
Oct 24 19:57:22 angelo-P15648 kernel: [14072.345211] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Hardware error detected. Restarting.
```

## Edit 2 (replying to @chili555)

It is **not** a dual boot. Only systems installed are Ubuntu.

You assumed the kernel version correctly.
`uname -r` outputs `5.14.14-051414-generic`

`dmesg | grep iwl` outputs:

```
[    2.794034] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.797944] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 02f0/0000, rev=0x354, rfid=0x0
[    2.798042] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

I removed backport from dkms tree using
`sudo dkms remove backport-iwlwifi/8324 --all`

`dkms status` now returns

```
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.11.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.14.14-051414-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
```

## Edit 3 (replying to @chili555)

Testing with kernel version `5.4.0-89-generic`

`dmesg | grep iwl` does not return anything...

`dkms status` returns

```
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.11.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.14.14-051414-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.4.0-89-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Have you tried to install `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`  ?

Comment: @nobody It is installed (output: `backport-iwlwifi-dkms is already the newest version (8324-0ubuntu3~20.04.4)`) but I am not sure if it is 'active'. Do you know how to make sure the system is trying to 'use' it?

To be honest: as I tried several approaches to solve the problem, I feel everything is tidy and I wonder if I can clean up or reset everything I installed during the last two days. Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: are you sure it is not a hardware issue?  `dkms status` and `uname -r` please. Also `rfkill list` and `grep -i error /var/log/kern.log`

Comment: @nobody outputs can be found in the edited question

Comment: `backport-iwlwifi`is not korrekt installed. It is added to dkms tree but not build nor installed in any kernel of yours.  the firmwares that are not found are in package `linux-firmware`  In my opinion the module iwlwifi crashes, because it 'thinks' somethiing wrong with the intel-microcode. but my knowledge for this is really restricted.I'm sorry maybe someone other can superiorly help than me.

Comment: `dkms install backport-iwlwifi/8324 -k 5.14.14-051414-generic` returns `Error!  The /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8324/5.14.14-051414-generic/x86_64/dkms.conf for module backport-iwlwifi includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.` @nobody Thank you anyway.

Comment: I don't believe that backport installs correctly for any kernel version above 5.4. I suggest that you remove it. Reboot into, I assume, kernel version 5.14.14 and show me: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` If this is a dual boot with Windows, please disable Fast Boot.

Comment: @chili555 I updated the question (see **Edit 2**).

Comment: @chili555 Maybe this line `i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=54947 end=54948) time 185 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1069, end 1080` of the error log might be interesting. It occurred ~3 hours before the iwlwifi driver first's error occurred. Just to remind you: Up until 4 days ago I never had (visible) problems with my wifi.

Comment: If you interrupt the boot process at the GRUB menu and boot into the earliest kernel version that you have, does the problem remain?  Perhaps it is 5.14.14 that is the issue.

Comment: @chili555 I will try it. However, have in mind that I only installed 5.14.14 in the process of tackling the problem with the `iwlwifi`.

Comment: "dmesg | grep iwl does not return anything..." How about: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Modprobe may produce an error that leads us to the solution.

Comment: @chili555 `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` returns no output.

Comment: Have you an older bionic iso for a live session? for testing?

Comment: Are you still working to solve this problem? I have a new idea (udev rule) and need a tester! Please reply.

Comment: maybe he is not but I would have the exact same problem if there is still need for a tester ;)

Comment: @relief.melone Please start a new question. I’ll be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I was able to sort it out by updating kernel from 5.15-5.19.