# Wifi and Bluetooth suddenly not working Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, iwlwifi

About a week ago, my computer abruptly disconnected from my Wi-Fi. Now I can't find the Wi-Fi menu in the settings and the Bluetooth is not working either, the toggle in the settings doesn't do anything. I tried various solutions from different forums, but none of them worked. Here is a list of outputs that may be useful.

1. `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

   ```
   [    3.810679] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22  
   [    3.810727] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family  
   [    3.810731] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized  
   [    3.810916] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized  
   [    3.810921] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized  
   [    3.810930] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized  
   [    3.946449] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 42 week 52 2015  
   [    3.948664] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 0  
   [    3.948670] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is disabled  
   [    3.948672] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is disabled  
   [    3.948675] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is disabled  
   [    3.948677] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled  
   [    3.948679] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 0 week 0 2000  
   [    3.948683] Bluetooth: hci0: No device address configured  
   [    3.949230] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file intel/ibt-17-0-0.sfi (-2)  
   [    3.951350] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -56  
   [    3.954741] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read MSFT supported features (-56)  
   [    4.296585] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3  
   [    4.296593] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
   [    4.296600] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
   ```

   I tried looking for the missing firmware file here: https://anduin.linuxfromscratch.org/sources/linux-firmware/intel/ but it's missing there too.
2. `dmesg | grep -i iwl`

   ```
   [    2.504113] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
   [    2.519800] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Can find a correct rfid for crf id 0x816
   [    2.519863] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
   ```
3. `lshw -class network`

   ```
     *-network UNCLAIMED       
          description: Network controller
          product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 14.3
          bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
          version: 30
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
          configuration: latency=0
          resources: memory:b431c000-b431ffff
   ```
4. `ifconfig -a`

   ```
   lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
           inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
           inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
           loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
           RX packets 13227  bytes 1142334 (1.1 MB)
           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
           TX packets 13227  bytes 1142334 (1.1 MB)
           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
   ```

To my understanding, the fact that `ifconfig` only shows a loopback interface and the status `UNCLAIMED network` indicate that my system somehow fails to recognize my network card.

I tried updating all the firmware files in `/usr/lib/firmware/intel` and also installing [the following package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kernel/linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-32-generic) following the advice found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1437504/1673888), but it didn't help.

I have Windows in dual boot, so I tried addressing the issue from there, but my network card was missing from the device manager and so was the Bluetooth: I even tried taking apart my PC thinking that maybe it could be a hardware issue (like some disconnected wires) but everything seems fine.

I tried my best, but I honestly have no idea what's going on, any input would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a BIOS reset to defaults?

Comment: Check the packages that are upgradable. It could be related to grub-efi or shim: sudo apt list --upgradable If grub-efi or shim packages appear, upgrade them: sudo apt install grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed

Comment: I have also the same issue in my ubuntu22.0. Did the fix above work?

Comment: go back to the previous kernel version to check the Bluetooth and the wi-fi

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1201618/1698042

Comment: already tried the options of iwlwifi backport, changing the kernel versions to both backward and upward. Nothing worked.  The wifi appears sometime when we start the machine and in between it will disappear. It will not appear again if we restart the machine. Don't know what exact scenario it appears and disappears. However, now I am using an external wifi dongle to connect to the internet OR inside office I use LAN cable. But when we use an external wifi adapter, the bluetooth turns off. As bluetooth is not so important for me and I need internet connection, I am adjusting with it now.

Comment: Try booting a Live system and see if it works there.

Comment: If windows doesn't show the hardware either, I'll second @KahnD's answer: Your hardware broke and needs to be replaced. That is called [obsolescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsolescence)

Comment: I tried everything. Suddenly today, it shown the wifi. But after a reboot, the same problem again. The main thing I noticed was that, when wifi works, bluetooth also works. When wifi is not there, bluetooth is also not available. Could there any frequency/channel overlapps that blocks each other so that none of them can operate correctly? I am sure that there isn't any problem with wifi card and all, that is why it works sometimes on some reboots.

Answer (score 1):

If it has disappeared from windows also, you likely have a hardware problem. You might get lucky checking your bios for a misconfiguration or maybe reflashing it.

Sometimes those CNVi modules can be replaced, they go in an m2 slot and I've seen them for sale less than $20.