# Error: "No Wi-Fi adapter found"

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Mi notebook air. But, I couldn't connect to the Wi-Fi and it tells me that "No Wi-Fi adapter found"

**Things I have Tried**

Followed the link https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html

Typed :

`lshw -C network`

Result:

```
 *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:b4210000-b4213fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u3
       serial: a6:db:bc:17:91:0f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.216 link=yes multicast=yes
```

To know about chipset,

```
lspci -vvnn | grep Network
```

Result

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
```

Driver for PCI device

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network | grep Kernel
```

Result:

```
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I also checked the kernel version

```
uname -srm
```

Result:

```
Linux 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64
```

Then from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html, I downloaded `iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0.tgz` based on kernel version and  copied the files in 
/lib/firmware although I am not sure if its correct. Then I restarted laptop. But still the Wi-Fi is not working.

Furthermore I followed the steps from [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180765/intel-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu), but Still not working.

Output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I have edited my question. Thank you it helped.