# Error: Wifi adapter not found after update

Tags: networking, iwlwifi

I was having the same issue a month ago as from my previous question.
[Error: "No Wi-Fi adapter found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202879/error-no-wi-fi-adapter-found). But it was solved after I followed:
[WiFi Adapter AX201 Not Found: Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196308/wifi-adapter-ax201-not-found-ubuntu-18-04).
Now I am again having the same issue after I updated my computer about a week ago.
The output of
 `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
    Kernel modules: wl, iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:02e8]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

My kernel version is **Linux 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64** and the version of my Ubuntu is **18.04**.
The output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b4210000-b4213fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u3
       serial: a6:db:bc:17:91:0f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.216 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem on 19.10. Reverting to linux-image-5.3.0-29-generic is a workaround. I would like to know what is going on here with iwlwifi and how I can get to run newer kernel updates and keep wifi working. What changed in 5.3.0.40?

Comment: @Christian. Thanks. Downgrading  the kernel actually worked. Still it would actually be helpful if iwlwifi  would work in newer version of kernel.

Comment: This must be an Ubuntu issue since earlier version of the 3.5 kernel  5.3.0-29 works while the latest  5.3.0-40 doesn't.