# Wifi not working on Dell Inspiron 14 5000

Tags: 18.04, wireless, dell, iwlwifi

We are having trouble with a wifi card on a Dell Inspiron 14 5000.

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS Cannot find the card.(It was working under Windows before drive ubuntu was installed) It appears to be an Intel 8086 card.

Here is a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pkiLEA6J) of information about the wifi on the system.

This issue is very simmilar to the problem discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180765/intel-wifi-card-not-working-on-ubuntu), however the solution does not appear to work.

The output of `dmesg | grep  iwl` is at this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HSRWxBgL)

The RT ucode appears to fail at loading.

Also the internet is functioning fine during install and whilst using live USB.

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251430

Answer (score 0):

It is just a hunch, but I think you miss the right firmware for your Wifi card. You could try to choose appropriate and [download firmware](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) and install it as instructed:

> 1. Copy the files into the distribution-specific firmware directory, /lib/firmware.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response but there didn't seem to be firmware for my specific card.  Any suggestions?